# how i check the string 'patient' using in_array in php

Tags: php

My array is:

```
$com_arr = Array(
    [0] => patient
    [1] => novel
    [2] => name
    [3] => monkey
    [4] => yourself
    [5] => novel
    [6] => buttons
    [7] => fifth
    [8] => stories
    [9] => English
    [10] => sign
    [11] => children
)
```

and variable `$values_for_ex[$r-1] = patient` and  my function looks like

```
if(in_array($values_for_ex[$r-1] ,$com_arr)) {   
     $replacements1 = "<span style='color:green;font-weight:700;' id='s'>"
                    . $values_for_ex[$r-1] . "</span>";
}
```

but  condition is not working.. why?

Comment: Where is $r coming from provide some more info

Comment: PHP **in_array** search is **case-sensitive** pls check both values are same

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected code. I have assumed the value of `$r` as 5 for testing purpose.

```
$com_arr = array(
'patient',
'novel',
'name',
'monkey',
'yourself',
'novel',
'buttons',
'fifth',
'stories',
'English',
'sign',
'children'
);
$r=5;// hard-coded for testing purpose
$values_for_ex[$r-1] = "patient";
if(in_array($values_for_ex[$r-1] ,$com_arr)) {   
$replacements1 = "<span style='color:green;font-weight:700;' id='s'>". $values_for_ex[$r-1] . "</span>";
    echo $replacements1;
}
```